# .htaccess rewrite issue with the mod_rewirte module

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following urls generated in the html

```
http://www.xxx.com/page/26/website-design-services?ajax=true
```

configured .htaccess syntax to read the value of the page id is

```
# BEGIN Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ page.php?section=$1  [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Rewrite
```

When i call the php file to do the get like below it returns only ajax part in the GET array. see below in page.php

```
print_r($_GET);
$url = $_GET['section'];
```

output is

```
Array
(
    [ajax] => true
)
```

any idea why it doesnt detect the other variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/ /page.php?section=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: It should have worked, is there any PHP/CMS framework running on your site?

Comment: no i dont use a framwork, maybe something internal i.e http.conf values are not setup properly, but for another site doing rewritting urls hosted on the same apache 2.2 server is working fine...strange

Comment: I edited my code to complete .htaccess and simplification of the rule. Can you try edited code now.

Comment: Most likely because of turning off `-MultiViews`